# Python 3.5: NLTK Download Default URL will not change

Tags: python, nltk

I've updated the DEFAULT_URL in downloader.py and I'm still getting the following error. I originally tried just nltk.downloader() and the file browser updated but when I tried to download, it still reverted back to the github site.

```
DEFAULT_URL = 'http://nltk.org/nltk_data/'
```

.

```
import nltk
nltk.set_proxy('proxyaddress',user=None)
dl = nltk.downloader.Downloader("http://nltk.org/nltk_data/")
dl.download('all')

[nltk_data] Downloading collection 'all'
[nltk_data]    |
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package abc to C:\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Error downloading 'abc' from
[nltk_data]    |     <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data
[nltk_data]    |     /gh-pages/packages/corpora/abc.zip>:   <urlopen
[nltk_data]    |     error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Why is this still defaulting to raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data?

Comment: There's no need to redefine `DEFAULT_URL`. It is ignored when you initialize the Downloader with your own url, as you do. Anyway I cannot reproduce your problem: It works as expected for me. Could your proxy be causing the problem?

Comment: @alexis it was my proxy. I tried again when I left my office and it worked fine.  I've used the same proxy in lots of other situations so I'm curious now if the "set_proxy" function doesn't work quite right.

Comment: `set_proxy` just calls `urllib.request.build_opener` and `install_opener`, which modify url handling. The problem must come from your proxy.

Comment: I've used "pip install --proxy=http://example.com:83 packagename"  countless times.  Why would that work but not for nltk?

Comment: I have no idea. I can only guess that it has something to do with caching by the proxy. Or maybe it's not the proxy but a logic error in a part of your code that didn't make it to the snippet in your question (if the proxy is set conditionally, there is some room for mistakes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your proxy. I can't say what's wrong with your proxy configuration, but initializing a downloader with a custom download url works as intended (there is no need to modify the nltk source in `nltk/downloader.py`):

```
dl = nltk.downloader.Downloader("http://example.com/my_corpus_data/index.xml")
```

Note that the custom url must resolve to an XML document describing the downloadable resources, in the format expected by the `nltk`; the code in your question points to the human-readable list at `http://nltk.org/nltk_data`, which will just result in an error. (Presumably your real code uses a different URL, and different code around the proxy settings.)

Anyway the problem has to be in your proxy, or the way you use it. The nltk's `set_proxy` function just calls a couple of functions from `urllib.request` to declare the proxy. It never comes near the nltk's `downloader` module, so there's no way it could affect the downloader's defaults.

Comment: I agree that it's my proxy since as soon as I left that environment it worked.  However I am confused how other utilities like R, CPAN client, pip, and few others all work using the same proxy addr:port.